# Where are MediaWiki's sessions set?

Tags: php, session, mediawiki

I have my own login system, and I want MediaWiki to share the same session. I'm trying to have my login system automatically login to my MediaWiki too which means I would probably have to share the same user database too.

Advice?

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth oauth maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but we use **[LDAP Authentication](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication)**.

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is what I need. I don't even know what LDAP is.

Answer (score 1):

The session is set in `includes/GlobalFunctions.php`.  If you want to fake a user login to mediawiki after the user logs in to your system, you'll need to make sure that the cookie parameters match (e.g. the cookie URL must be the same); have a look at the arguments they use to construct it in the call to `session_set_cookie_params`.

Once you've got the session set up correctly, you'll need to load a user and inject it to the session so that when mediawiki goes to check if the user is logged in, it finds your injected user and goes right ahead.  Look in `includes/User.php`, the `User::loadFromSession` call looks like a promising place to figure out what they expect to find there.

Comment: This sounds promising, I am going to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you make changes directly to the MediaWiki source, you'll have a hard time upgrading to future versions of MediaWiki.  It would be much better to use the existing authentication plugin framework:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/AuthPlugin

You didn't specify what your existing login system is, but if you're lucky somebody has already built a plugin for it:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:User_identity_extensions